# How can I split an array into two arrays with alternating elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to split an array of strings into two arrays. 
However, when I push the strings into the new arrays, it should be alternating. So, if the array is:

```
let alph = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

Then the new arrays would look like:

```
firstArr = [a,c,e]
secondArr = [b,d,f]
```

How can I do it so I'm not repeating myself? I have the following code, and it works, but I do not want to write two of the same filter functions (keep things DRY):

```
let firstArr = alph.filter((letter, index) => {
  return index % 2 === 0;
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could take an array of the both arrays and take the index as indicator for the wanted array for pushing.

```js
let alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    first = [],
    second = [],
    temp = [first, second];
    
alph.forEach((v, i) => temp[i % 2].push(v));

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `filter` creates one array, you need two, or use e.g. `forEach`

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"], firstArr = [], secondArr = [];

arr.forEach( (a,i) => {
  (i % 2 === 0) ? firstArr.push(a) : secondArr.push(a);
})

console.log(firstArr)
console.log(secondArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

For better readability there's nothing wrong with having separate filter functions for these.  To clean it up a little you could use arrow functions and make them 1 liners and then pass them in the filter function, like:

```
const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const filterByEvens = (letter, index) => index % 2 === 0;
const filterByOdds = (letter, index) => index % 2 !== 0;
const evens = alpha.filter(filterByEvens);
const odds = alpha.filter(filterByOdds);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this :

```js
const alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const result = alph.reduce((acc, letter, ndx) => {
  acc[ndx % 2] = acc[ndx % 2] || [];
  acc[ndx % 2].push(letter);
  return acc;
}, []);

const [firstArr, secondArr] = result;

console.log(firstArr, secondArr);
```